# Pandas iloc returning empty result

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying filter pandas rows based on two columns values `CN` and `CAN`(present in column `2`) but I am getting **empty result** with the following snippet.

`data = df.loc[(df[2] == 'CN') & (df[2] == 'CAN')]`

Please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried putting parentheses around df[2] == 'CAN'?

Comment: @muzzyq  I have updated the question. I am now getting `Invalid Syntax` error

Comment: you have one too many closing square brackets now

Comment: @muzzyq I have updated, again getting empty result

Comment: **Update** :- got the result when i did `df.loc[(df[2] == 'CN') | (df[2] == 'CAN')]`
It gave me the results of both `CN` and `CAN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df[2]` can't be both `'CN'` AND `'CAN'` at the same time.

Try using `|` instead of `&`:

```
data = df.loc[(df[2] == 'CN') | (df[2] == 'CAN')]
```

This will return rows where the OR condition is satisfied.